# count a how many times a letter appears in javascript using indexOf

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexof

I am trying to count how many times a letter appears in a string using indexOf(). Could you advise me on where I am going wrong in my code. Thanks!

```
var string = 'Lets find l as many times as we can. Love is natural, love you lots';

var myFunc = function (letter) {
    newString = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < letter.length; i += 1) {
        if (string.indexOf('l')) {
            newString += 1;
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Are you insistent upon some method using `.indexOf()`? there are easier ways here.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - nope, I was just trying to understand how to use it.

Comment: `string.search(/l/g)`

Comment: `string.split('').filter(function(e) {return e=='l'}).length`

Comment: `string.match(/l/g).length`

Comment: [Performance tests](http://jsperf.com/finding-a-letter-with-indexof) between P.S.W.G.'s, Adam Rackis', and my answers.

Comment: @adeneo Note that [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) returns the index of the first match, not the number of matches.

Comment: @ChristopherW - interesting, thanks.  I was honestly surprised the split() version of PSWGs answer wasn't a lot faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of this

```
if (string.indexOf('l')) {
    newString += 1;
}
```

You can use [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) or even direct indexing to check each letter of a string.

Like this

```
if (letter[i] == 'l') {
    newString += 1;
}
```

or this

```
if (letter.charAt(i) == 'l') {
    newString += 1;
}
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3uFn5/)

---

Note that if you were to use `indexOf` you'd want to call it directly on the string in question, like this

`letter.indexOf('l')`

Comment: Good call on my `letter.indexOf('l')` I see my error there. Thanks for enlightening me :) It was very helpful!

Answer (score 7):

The other answer is perfectly good, but in case you really want a solution using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) (as the title of your question suggests), you need to provide it a second parameter, to tell it where to start looking for the next occurrence:

```
var myFunc = function (str) {
    var i = 0, c = 0;
    do {
        i = str.indexOf('l', i);
    } while (++i && ++c);
    return c;
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/N32N9/)

But, if using `indexOf` is *not* a requirement, you can simplify this to:

```
var myFunc = function (str) {
    return str.split('l').length - 1;
}
```

Comment: `return str.split('l').length - 1;` - Simplicity at it's finest.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive method if you are insistent upon `indexOf`:

```
var myFunc = function (str, letter) {
    var count = 0,
        p = str.indexOf(letter);

    if (p > -1) {
        count += (1 + myFunc(str.slice(p + 1, str.length - 1), letter));
    }

    return count;
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLj5b/)